# strange syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I tried to run this simple code in an IRB session, but I got this error:

```
[9] pry(main)> puts {x: 1}
SyntaxError: unexpected ':', expecting '}'
puts {x: 1}
        ^
```

I know that I can run the same code like this:

```
[12] pry(main)> y = {x: 1}
=> {:x=>1}
[13] pry(main)> puts y
{:x=>1}
```

or:

```
[14] pry(main)> puts "",{x: 1}
{:x=>1}
```

What is that the problem in the first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curly braces can denote either a block literal or a `Hash` literal. In this case, it is interpreted as a block literal, and `x: 1` is not a syntactically valid Ruby expression.

You can provide the argument list with parentheses to resolve this ambiguity:

```
puts({x: 1})
```

Or alternatively, Ruby allows you to leave out the curly braces if the last argument to a method is a `Hash`:

```
puts(x: 1)
```

And in that case, you can again leave out the parentheses, because there is no confusion with a block:

```
puts x: 1
```

Your last example works, because the comma tells the parser that the argument list isn't finished yet and what follows couldn't possibly be a block.

Comment: Humm. Yeah!! Exactly this is the reason.. I went with wrong explanation..I need a break!! :))

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `{}` is parsed as a block. In the second it is parsed as a hash.

Example:

```
def foo(opts = nil, &block)
  p opts
  p block
end

foo { 'a' } #=> nil #<Proc:0x007f12144f7f68@(pry):12>
foo({a: 'a'}) #=> {:a=>"a"} nil
foo a: 'a' #=> {:a=>"a"} nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby thinks your passing a **block**. For passing a hash, try:

```
puts({x: 1})
```

or

```
puts(x: 1)
```